# Using the java System.getProperty("Import")

Tags: java, system-properties

I was doing some work for college and my main runs this:

```
Spreadsheet sheet = new Spreadsheet(0,0);
SpreadsheetManager manager = new SpreadsheetManager(sheet);

/* Read an Import file, if any */
String filename = System.getProperty("import");

if (filename != null)
    sheet.parseInputFile(filename, sheet);
```

Thing is, when I actually try to import a file it doesn't do what is supposed to and the filename is **always** null, so it never reaches my parseInputFile.

My teachers made a bunch of code for different programming exercises that do similar things available, and I've also looked at projects my colleagues did in previous years, but every single one does what I am doing above.

I have to run my program like this: `java -Dimport=A-002-002-M-ok.import calc.textui.Calc` otherwise none of the tests given by the teachers will run.

I'm sorry if this is not a useful question, but I've tried looking everywhere. If anyone could explain how the `System.getProperty("import")` works and why it isn't working in this case, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Where and how do you set that property?

Comment: What are you trying to obtain with the property "import"?

Comment: @luanjot I'm trying to import a text file with a bunch of initialisations for my spreadsheet.

Comment: @Ingo how would I do that? Because I haven't seen any example of that anywhere :/

Comment: @RitaPereira You can do it with System.setProperty("import", "yourfile.txt"), but I don't know if that's what you want...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run your program with:

```
java -Dimport=foo
```

then the method call

```
System.getProperty("import")
```

should return "foo".

Is ist possible that you write a tiny example program to convince yourself? Without any SheetManagers and all stuff, just

```
class ItWorks {
public static void main(String[] args) {
   System.out.println(System.getProperty("import"));
}
}
```

Call it thus

```
java -Dimport=indeed ItWorks
```

and report what happens.

That being said: if you want to pass command line arguments, why don't you use the facility for command line arguments? (i.e. the String[] array passed to main?)

You could then call your program like this:

```
java calc.textui.Calc my-nice-spreadsheet.data
```

=====================================================

Please write the follwoing in your `calc.textui.Calc` program **immediately** after the open brace of your class definition:

```
public class Calc ..... {   // a line like this already exists
    // insert next line here
    public static String filename = System.getProperty("import");

    // rest of your class, as before.
}
```

Then comment out the `getProperty()`  line in your method that didn't work, but leave the rest including the `System.out.println(filename);`

Does it change?

Comment: It returns "indeed"... but the same line in my original code returns null... As for the latter, the tests ran by the teachers were called using  java -Dimport=A-002-002-M-ok.import calc.textui.Calc; so I'm not sure if I could do that.

Comment: @RitaPereira "but the same line in my original code returns null" how do you know this? And, BTW, you can of course run your small test program with ` -Dimport=A-002-002-M-ok.import`

Comment: I've tried adding a System.out.println(filename) and it returns null, shouldn't it return A-002-002-M-ok.import?

Comment: Yes, it should. And, as you see in your other program, it will. But if it doesn't this means there is something in your code we don't know yet.

Comment: @RitaPereira Please see my suggestion how to track the bug.

Comment: it tells me I have an illegal start of expression.

Comment: @RitaPereira look, I really want to help you, because the problem interests me. But how about a bit more cooperation from your side? Such as to show error messages, along with the code lines they refer to?

Comment: sorry.
    `calc/textui/Calc.java:25: error: illegal start of expression
     public static String filename = System.getProperty("import");
     ^
    calc/textui/Calc.java:25: error: illegal start of expression
     public static String filename = System.getProperty("import");
            ^
    calc/textui/Calc.java:25: error: ';' expected
     public static String filename = System.getProperty("import");
                         ^
    3 errors`

Comment: Please show the first non-empty line that also does not only contain comments before line 25. You can maybe do that by editing your question, that should look better.

Comment: I can't edit the comment correctly..... sorry. the first error refers to the public, the second to the static, and the third to the space between String and filename

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) { this is the first non-empty line before the 25

Comment: @RitaPereira What did I tell you where you should insert the `public static String filename = ....`

Comment: immediately after the open brace of your **class** definition

Comment: Look, I'm really sorry, I've been working on this all night and I didn't notice I had made that mistake. I'm really thankful for your help and it does work just fine now.

Comment: Does it mean it processes the file now? That means your prof is a very though guy, because he nastily inserted something like `System.setProperty("import", null)` into some code that usually runs before your own code. That's why I wanted you to put it there so you could intercept the value before he destroys it.

Comment: @RitaPereira Since you are new here, allow me to mention that you can vote up answers you found helpful and also mark the best answer. This will also increase your reputation.

Comment: Yes, it does process the file. Your explanation makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you take a look at the [documentation of `System.getProperty()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html).

Basically it retrieves a value from the system, either already present or set by you.

To avoid retrieving `null` you can use another method signature that specify a default value:

`System.getProperty("import", "file.txt");`

To set a System property, you can specify it at launch:

> java -Dimport="file.txt" your_application

or set it programatically :

> System.setProperty("import", "file.txt");

Comment: The thing is I don't want to import a "static" single file, but a battery of different tests with different initialisations with different names.

Comment: then you should probably take a look at the java command line arguments. Each time you call your application with a different path to the file you want to import. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html

Comment: This is what I'm doing at launch: java -Dimport=A-002-002-M-ok.import calc.textui.Calc;    I'm sorry to be bothering you with this, but I'm really not getting where is this incorrect and I'm getting more and more confused with it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe system properties are not the most indicated way to do that (depends on your application).
You could also use command line arguments to pass the file name to your `main` method:

```
public class CommandLineExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length < 1) {
            System.err.println("usage: CommandLineExample <filename>");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String filename = args[0];
        if (filename !=null && !filename.isEmpty()) {
            ...
        }
    }
```

}

Your program should be called as:

```
    java CommandLineExample theFileName
```

the string "theFileName" will be passed to the main method in args[0] (any additional words will be passed in subsequent positions of args {args[1], args[2], ...})

**EDIT**
if the program must be called with

```
    java -Dimport=filename ...
```

then `System.getProperty("import")` will return the filename.
Confirm that you are calling the correct program (class name, package, version, last compile was successful, ...) and also check that the property is not mistyped like `java -Dinport=A-...` or has additional spaces, uppercase letters...

Comment: I have to run my program like this though: java -Dimport=A-002-002-M-ok.import calc.textui.Calc otherwise none of the tests given by the teachers will run

Comment: @RitaPereira two possibilities: calling the wrong program, or not setting "import". Are you sure it is not being called with "java -Dinport=A-..." or seome other typo like spaces, uppercases, ...